# Git for Cygwin and file permissions

Tags: git, cygwin, tortoise-git

Why does git for Cygwin always get confused with file permissions? The file didn't change. TortoiseGIT doesn't think it is modified. DOS Git doesn't think it's modified.

```
$ git diff README.md
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
old mode 100644
new mode 100755

$ ls -l README.md
-rwx------+ 1 Chloe None 824 Sep  4 00:55 README.md

$ which git
/usr/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.4

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.2-WOW64 xps 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:39 i686 Cygwin
```

Comment: What git version does git cygwin uses? A similar question (on DOS, not cygwin) mentioned that a more recent client deals with permissions more consistently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18842322/6309

Comment: @VonC Of course... added.

Comment: That seems recent enough ;) No clue for now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `README.md` in your working directory has user execute permissions set, but not so in the index, hence the reported difference.

Try this and see if it helps:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

For example, I recreated something that looks like your situation, and here's what I get (with both settings of `core.filemode`):

```
$ git config core.filemode true

$ git diff foo.txt
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
old mode 100644
new mode 100755

$ ls -l foo.txt
-rwx------+ 1 david Domain Users 0 Jul  2 12:40 foo.txt*

$ git config core.filemode false

$ git diff foo.txt

$
```

Warning, I'm using different versions of Cygwin and Git:

```
$ which git; git --version; uname -a
/usr/bin/git
git version 1.7.9
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 XXXXXX 1.7.30(0.272/5/3) 2014-05-23 10:36 i686 Cygwin
```